# Change gravity forms confirmation redirect query string to include entry id

Tags: redirect, plugin-gravity-forms, query-string

I need to somehow insert the entry id from a Gravity Forms submission into a redirect confirmation. My problem is, that when attempting to create a confirmation via the admin interface, I *can* insert the entry id into a hidden field, but it doesn't exist until after everything fires, rendering my query string blank (although the others do still work). I was thinking that by hooking into `gform_confirmation`, I would have access by grabbing the confirmation before it happened and changing it on the fly but that doesn't seem to be working either. Here's what I currently have entered into my **functions.php**:

```
add_action("gform_confirmation", "custom_confirm", 10, 4);
function custom_confirm($confirmation, $form, $lead, $is_ajax){

    $url = $confirmation . "&rma" . $lead['id'];

    $confirmation = array('redirect' => $url);

}
```

As you can see, I'm simply trying to tack on "&rma=[*entry-id*]" although I'm not sure `$lead['id']` is even the right variable I need to be accessing. Also not sure if the last assignment is changing the URL in the proper way.

TL;DR: I need to change the confirmation redirect to include the entry ID and I'm wondering if it's even possible.

Comment: For any one else looking for entry Id , with latest version 1.9.x and above you can simply pass the entry id as parameter in the url like lead={entry_id}
to do this goto FORM CONFIRMATION settings in the text area labelled "Redirect Query String" add lead={entry_id} , you can than use the url query string using $_GET['lead'] to retrieve the entry id

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out. I did have some syntax errors in my code. Should have been `add_filter` instead of `add_action.` Also, `$confirmation` is an array and was never returned. I think my brain was just tired from looking at this for so long. Anyways, here's what I did to fix it.

```
add_filter("gform_confirmation", "confirm_change", 10, 4);
function confirm_change($confirmation, $form, $lead, $ajax){

    $url = get_bloginfo('url') ."/thank-you/?page=". $lead['1']. "&rma=" . ($lead['id']);

    $confirmation = array('redirect' => $url);
    return $confirmation;
}
```

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. Make sure to mark your answer as **Accepted** once you're able (I think it's a two-day wait, IIRC).

Comment: Awesome. This snippet saved my few hours. Thanks for sharing.